# URL / Server to download date and time information from on client machine desktop software

Tags: url, date, time, client-server

simple but I guess useful information after answered:
I need an URL to download date/time information from on client's machine ( inside desktop application ) , another worlds , to send request to ( POST/GET ) and get response from with current date and time in some comfort to parse format ( .txt or .csv for example ) like for example we download stocks data ( [Some intersting stuff](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm)  )

I've looked through www but can't find any server / web resource URL that responds with date/time.

Who knows what web resource ( url , server address ) responds with current date/time ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, normally **every** web server is supposed to tell you it's own idea of the current date and time, on **every** single request. Look for the `Date` header field.

Example (shell command):

```
$ lynx -head -mime_header http://stackoverflow.com/ | grep ^Date:
Date: Fri, 16 Dec 2011 13:01:04 GMT
```

**Note:** For time synchronization over the Internet, you should
normally use the [NTP protocol](http://ntp.org/). However, as stated on
[this page](http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/vendors.html), “You must get
approval from the server operator before you hardcode any IP addresses
or hostnames.”

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly, it's in the HTTP Date header. I edited the answer with an example. I will not post C(++) code as it would depend on the API you are using, and would be trivial anyway.

Comment: Yes.Thank you Edgar. Solved using Date header field of http response.